# Retrieving field values in ASP.net after checkbox has been selected

Tags: asp.net

[image: Retrieving Field details]

HI All - PLease refer the attached screen shot. The status and Role fields are enclosed in a panel for each check box.

On click of the submit button, only data for the selected check box should be picked up. Can you please help with a pseudo code how the data  (Status and Role) for the first and third checkbox can be retrieved.

These controls are kept in a table. No grid view is being used.

Thanks for the help.
Yagya

Comment: Hello Pranay - This is not the home work. There is another open question from me related to MAC address using C# on browser machine. Do you want to try this :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All data will be returned to the server, but that's not a problem, just act on whatever the spec says.

I assume that the checkboxes are hardcoded `<asp:Checkbox />` or `<input type="checkbox" runat="server" />` controls, then it's simple:

Assuming `<input type="checkbox" runat="server" id="reporting" />` then:

```
public override void OnLoad(Object sender, EventArgs e) {
    if( this.reporting.Checked ) {
        String status = this.reportingStatus.Value;
        String role   = this.reportingRole.Value;
        // your logic here
    } else if( this.assignment.Checked ) { 
        // etc
    } else... // and so on
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot David for the speedy response. You are correct. The IDs are hard coded.